# MS Access Query field name based on Dlookup

Tags: ms-access

I have Client table with ID and Moneycd. I want to query Payroll's Moneycd field as Money for a Client.

For example, Client 1 has Moneycd IRA in Client table. That IRA is field name for Client 1.   For Client 1, I want to query Payroll;'s IRA field (as alias Money) by referring to Moneycd.

```
Public Sub GetMoney()
 
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database  
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef  
   Dim strSQL As String  
   Dim StrLookup As Field  
    
   Set dbs = CurrentDb  
   Set StrLookup = DLookup("[moneyCd]", "Client Details", "[ClientID] = '22793'")  

   strSQL = "SELECT StrLookup FROM Payroll as Money;"  
   Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("test", strSQL)  
  
End Sub
```

Comment: it seems like your tables are not normalized. So reviewing normalization and then normalizing your tables should help.   Please show the tables you have, the query you attempted and the query results you want: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A picture would really help.  You can edit your original question using the "edit" button just below the tags at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Concatenate variable: `strSQL = "SELECT [" & StrLookup & "] FROM Payroll as Money;"`

Comment: Error on Set StrLookup stating object required.  Any suggestion?